# Installing Xcode from App Store doesn't seem to work

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I'm having a rather odd problem.

I've installed Xcode from the App Store three times now. No errors are being presented to me, but after installing Xcode I can press Open (in the App Store) and nothing happens. Refresh the view in App Store and I can press Install again.

What's going on?

I'm on Sierra 10.12.4 if that matters.

Comment: Does **Xcode.app** appear in the **/Applications** folder?

Comment: @GrahamMiln Yes, it does. I can actually open it, just not from spotlight. And I can still install it from the App Store. Odd...

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the .app file to Spotlight's index?  Granted, you shouldn't need to do this but if it is a bug, this might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given **Xcode.app** appears in the **/Applications** and can be launched, the behaviour suggests Spotlight has yet to notice the newly installed application.

It is likely Apple's App Store application uses Spotlight to determine if applications are installed; thus the ability to Install Xcode.app re-appears on refresh.

I suspect the bug will vanish once Spotlight re-indexes your applications.

Consider telling Apple directly about this bug through their [feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).